# Python - Move elements in a list of dictionaries to the end of the list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I've a list of dictionaries like this:

```
lst = [
  {'id': 1, 'language': 'it'},
  {'id': 2, 'language': 'en'},
  {'id': 3, 'language': 'es'},
  {'id': 4, 'language': 'en'}
  ]
```

I want to move every dictionary that has `language != 'en'` to the end of the list while keeping the order of other of results. So the list should look like:

```
lst = [ 
  {'id': 2, 'language': 'en'},
  {'id': 4, 'language': 'en'},
  {'id': 1, 'language': 'it'},
  {'id': 3, 'language': 'es'}
  ]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use sorting. Idea is to sort on whether is equal to `'language'` or not. If language is equal to `'en'` then key function will return `False` else `True` (`False` < `True`). As Python's sort is stable the order will be preserved.

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x['language'] != 'en')
[{'id': 2, 'language': 'en'},
 {'id': 4, 'language': 'en'},
 {'id': 1, 'language': 'it'},
 {'id': 3, 'language': 'es'}]
```

Comment: you could add that it works because python sort is _stable_

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yep, I was in middle of editing it. :-)